# Parse This IP To Be The Right Length?

Tags: c, winapi, ip

For something I am doing I would like to get the external IP of the PC running the program (written in C). So far I have found the best way is to connect to a site that simply displays the IP of the visitor, and then parse the webpage for the IP. The first part was easy, but when I display the buffer I read the page (which only visibly consisted of my IP) I get a few random extra symbols/characters after the IP. Here is the code I am using ATM (simplified to exclude other stuff):

```
HINTERNET OpenInternet = NULL;
HINTERNET GetIP = NULL;
DWORD BytesRead = 0;
char IPGrabbed[30];

OpenInternet = InternetOpen("Microsoft Internet Explorer", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (OpenInternet == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

GetIP = InternetOpenUrl(OpenInternet, "http://api.externalip.net/ip/", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
if (GetIP == NULL) 
    return 1;

if (!InternetReadFile(GetIP, &IPGrabbed, sizeof(IPGrabbed), &BytesRead)) 
    return 1;

printf("IP: %s", IPGrabbed);
getchar();
```

I also tried parsing through IPGrabbed stopping at any '\n' or '\r' (because it displays the weird characters on the line below the IP when I printf() it) and then copying everything up till there to another char array, but got the same result. Could anyone help me figure out what is going on here? Thank you.

Comment: Sample input and output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the buffer to all `0`s and then read one character less then the buffer to read into provides.

This way the `0`-terminator a C-"string" relies on is provided implicitly.

```
char IPGrabbed[30] = ""; /* Initialise the buffer to all `0`s ... */

[...]

/* ... and then read one character less then the buffer to read into provides. */
if (!InternetReadFile(GetIP, &IPGrabbed, sizeof(IPGrabbed) - 1, &BytesRead)) 
  return 1;

fprintf(stderr, "IP: %s", IPGrabbed); /* Print to stderr, as it's not buffered so 
                                  everything appear immediately to the console. */
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem for the most part, but now there are just a lot of blank characters shown after the IP. When I read the strlen of the char array I get 14 even though it is not that much. Is there any way to find out what these blank characters after the IP are? Thanks for your answer, seems pretty obvious now.

Comment: @RobLennon: What do you expected them be, then just blanks?

Comment: I was really asking how I would figure out what those characters are so I can truncate the string there, but I figured our how. I just setup a for loop which goes through each character of IPGrabbed, and if is neither a numeral or a period it knows where the IP really ends. Thanks.

Comment: @RobLennon: Your are welcome and I'm glad to see I have answered your question. If you even liked my answer you are free to also upvote it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The result from `InternetReadFile` is not null-terminated, you need to add a null character to the end of the string by code after the read is successful:

```
IPGrabbed[BytesRead] = 0;
```

Edit 1
As suggested in the comment by Jonathan Potter, the above code may be subjected to a buffer overflow error if the site being accessed is returning anything longer than a IP string (maximum 16 characters).
Suggest to change the `InternetReadFile` to read 1 less of the buffer length instead of full buffer length to eliminate the above problem.

```
InternetReadFile(GetIP, &IPGrabbed, sizeof(IPGrabbed)-1, &BytesRead)
```

Comment: Buffer overflow if `BytesRead == sizeof(IPGrabbed)`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thanks for your tip, your suggestion is being incorporated into the answer.